# Empty Plot when dealing with a huge number of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I attempted to use the code below to plot a graph to show the Speed per hour by days.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
import glob, os

taxi_df = pd.read_csv('ChicagoTaxi.csv')

taxi_df['trip_start_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(taxi_df['trip_start_timestamp'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors = 'raise')
taxi_df['trip_end_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(taxi_df['trip_end_timestamp'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors = 'raise')

#For filtering away any zero values when trip_Seconds or trip_miles = 0
filterZero = taxi_df[(taxi_df.trip_seconds != 0) & (taxi_df.trip_miles != 0)]
filterZero['trip_seconds'] = filterZero['trip_seconds']/60
filterZero['trip_seconds'] = filterZero['trip_seconds'].apply(lambda x: round(x,0))
filterZero['speed'] = filterZero['trip_miles']/filterZero['trip_seconds']
filterZero['speed'] *= 60

filterZero = filterZero.reset_index(drop=True)

filterZero.groupby(filterZero['trip_start_timestamp'].dt.strftime('%w'))['speed'].mean().plot()
plt.xlabel('Day')
plt.ylabel('Speed(Miles per Minutes)')
plt.title('Mean Miles per Hour By Days')
plt.show() #Not working
```

Example rows

```
0        2016-01-13 06:15:00   8.000000
1        2016-01-22 09:30:00  10.500000
```

Small Dataset : [1250219 rows x 2 columns]

Big Dataset: [15172212 rows x 2 columns]

For a smaller dataset the code works perfectly and the plot is shown. However when I attempted to use a dataset with 15 million rows the plot shown was empty as the values were "inf" despite running mean(). Am i doing something wrong here?

```
0    inf
1    inf
...
5    inf
6    inf
```

The speed is "Miles Per Hour" by day! I was trying out all time format so there is a mismatch in the picture sorry.

Image of failed Plotting(Larger Dataset):

[image]

Image of successful Plotting(Smaller Dataset):

[image]

Comment: I somehow doubt that the plot is really empty. It could rather be that the plotted part is at the very edge or outside the axes.

Comment: Zoom out lots - just in case

Comment: I have updated the questions with two images showing the plotting of the smaller and the larger dataset.

Comment: In any case I doubt we can help you because we do not have the dataset available. If you manage to provide a [mcve] of the issue, one may have a further look.

Comment: Your x axis is the same for both. Have you set the x limits for the smaller dataset and forgot to change them when you switched to the larger dataset?

Comment: I have updated the question with the codes needed to replicate the error along with the dataset download link. I hope this helps

@DavidG the x axis is suppose to be the same as it is being plotted by days (0 = Sat 1 = Mon.... 6 = Sun)

Note: As i do not have enough reputation to post links i used a space to break it.

Comment: I don't think you expect anyone to download your 2.3 GB datafile. It would also be questionable if plotting so many values makes any sense at all (you would probably run out of memory if you plot all points). If part of the dataset is plotted fine, try to find the subset which does not work correctly (if this should be the issue).

Comment: I assume some of the values in your dataset are equal to `inf`, which makes `mean()` return `inf` in all cases. You probably need to filter out those values for your code to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really be sure because you do not provide a real example of your dataset, but I'm pretty sure your problem comes from the column `trip_seconds`.

See these two lines:

```
filterZero['trip_seconds'] = filterZero['trip_seconds']/60
filterZero['trip_seconds'] = filterZero['trip_seconds'].apply(lambda x: round(x,0))
```

If some of your values in the column `trip_seconds` are ≤ 30, then this line will round them to 0.0.

```
filterZero['speed'] = filterZero['trip_miles']/filterZero['trip_seconds']
```

Therefore this line will be filled with some `inf` values (as anything / 0.0 = inf). Taking the `mean()` of an array with `inf` values will return `inf` regardless.

Two things to consider:

1. if your values in the column `trip_seconds` are actually in seconds, then after dividing your values by 60, they will be in minutes, which will make your speed in miles per minutes, not per hour.
2. You should try without rounding the times

Comment: Apparently that was really the problem. Thank you for pointing it out. I never expected the possibility of getting zeros because the min function from pandas showed 60.